# OpenRecordset and Eval()

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, input, parameters

General explanation of my program:

1. I do reference controls on form for user input. (start Date ex)
   8/1/2017  and End Date ex 8/31/2017)
2. Then my query runs based on the parameter and returns a single value: ex) 12345.23
3. Run the VBA function.

Problem: the `querydef` knows nothing about the previously opened query. Therefore, I would like to supply the parameters in VBA but I'm clueless from this point:

```
Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("2_Total")
Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset
For Each prm In qry.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Value)
Next
```

my SQL code :

```
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
HAVING (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [Forms]![RUN]![textBeginOrderDate] And [Forms]![RUN]![textendorderdate]));
```

Here is the full code:

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Public Function TRANS2()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim acRng As Variant
    Dim xlRow As Integer

    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\J\Desktop\August 2017.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Totals")

    xlRow = (xlWS.Columns("K").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("2_Total")
    Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset
    For Each prm In qry.Parameters
        prm.Value = Eval(prm.Value)
    Next

    Dim c As Integer
    c = 11   'C is the one that stores column number, in which c=1 means column A, 11 is for column K, 12 for Column L
    xlRow = xlRow + 11

     Do Until rst.EOF
        For Each acRng In rst.Fields
            xlWS.Cells(xlRow, c).Formula = acRng
            c = c + 1
        Next acRng
        xlRow = xlRow + 1
        c = 1
        rst.MoveNext
        If xlRow > 25 Then GoTo rq_Exit
    Loop


rq_Exit:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    xlWB.Close acSaveYes
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Function

End Function
```

p.s. I could have set the cell to value returned by DSum() but I would like to do the way I did. 
My good reference is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx.

> Edit:

```
Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("2_Total")

For Each prm In qry.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Value)
Next
Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset
```

I moved `Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset` after For Each, and now I'm getting

> The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.

on line   `prm.Value = Eval(prm.Value)`
Any advice on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query is syntactically wrong. You can't use `HAVING` clause without the `GROUP BY` clause. I think you need to use the `WHERE` clause instead like below :

```
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [Forms]![RUN]![textBeginOrderDate] 
And [Forms]![RUN]![textendorderdate]));
```

Comment: That is a good point! But I'm getting 'too few parameters. expected 2.' error on Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset. i don't think the querydef knows about the parameter

Comment: Would you please take a look at the edit? I would highly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!